# Using a a particular entry in a field to calculate something with entries in the same field in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, office365

I want to make a query that calculates how many times are the land massess of countries bigger than the land mass of a certain country.

How do I make a query that does that?

Edit:

[image: Example data]

Comment: Edit question to post table of example data.

Comment: Please show example of tables.

Comment: It is preferable to post data as a table in question, not an image. This allows readers to more easily transfer data to a local file instead of having to do data input. It is also helpful to provide example of desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a cartesian product with a single record:

```sql
select a.*, a.landmass / c.landmass as multiple
from table a, (select b.landmass from table b where b.country = 'UK') c
```

The above example assumes that your table is called `table` containing fields `country` and `landmass`, with a single record per country.

---

Now that you have uploaded sample data, the query may be written:

```sql
select a.*, a.terulet / c.terulet as multiple
from table a, (select b.terulet from table b where b.orszag = 'UK') c
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @fajank0 You're most welcome - please mark my answer as the solution if it sufficiently answered your question, so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site.